# Is every antisymmetric k-linear transformation alternate?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

> Definition 1. Let $V$ and $W$ be linear spaces over field $\mathbb{F}$. A function $f:V^k\to W$ is *$k$-linear* if it is linear over each entry separately.
>
> Definition 2: A $k$-linear function $f$ is said to be *alternate* if
>   $$
> f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_k) = 0
> $$
>   if $v_i = v_j$ for some $1\le i<j\le k$.
>
> Definition 3: A *$k$-linear* function $f$ is said to be *antisymmetric* if
>   $$
> f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_k) = -f(v_1,\dots,v_j,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)
> $$
>   for every $1\le i<j\le k$.

I have proved that if a $f$ satisfies (2) then it satisfies (3). I want to prove or disprove the reverse. I tried to find one myself and also searched the web and found no counterexamples so I wonder if it is true, but I tried to show it and I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Take $v_i=v_j$ in (3).

Answer (score 4):

They are equivalent if the field does not have characteristic $2$.

Over a field of characteristic $2$, antisymmetry is equivalent to symmetry:
alternation is a strictly stronger property. As a trivial example, let $V=k$
where $k$ has characteristic $2$. Then there is no nonzero alternating
form on $V\times V$. Yet $(a,b)\mapsto ab$ is (anti)symmetric on $V\times V$.

Comment: Okay, but it's not clear to me yet where to use the hypothesis of field with $car(\mathbb{F})\ne 2$

Comment: (Or $char(\mathbb{F}) = 2$)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt, can someone check my arguments please?

Assume $f$ satisfing (3). Let $1\le i<j\le k$ for some $i,j$. Then
$$
f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k) = -f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)
$$
then
$$
f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)+f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k) = 0
$$
and if $char(\mathbb{F})\ne 2$ then this implies that $f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)=0$ so $f$ is alternate. If $char(\mathbb{F})=2$ then we may have $f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)+f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k) = 0$ with $f(v_1,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_i,\dots,v_k)\ne 0$.

Is this correct?