# Basis-independent derivation of the fact that the determinant of the composition of two linear maps is the product of the determinant of each

Tags: differential-geometry, determinant, tensors, multilinear-algebra

*A* maximal form $\omega$ on $V$ is defined as an alternating type $(0, n)$ tensor (where $\dim V = n$). From there, the determinant is defined as,
$$ \det \phi \equiv \dfrac{\omega\left(\phi(e_1), \dots, \phi(e_n)\right)}{\omega\left(e_1, \dots, e_n \right)}.$$

One can show that this definition of the determinant is independent of the choice of both a maximal form and a basis. I'm interested in knowing whether it's possible to show from this definition that $\det (\phi \circ \psi) = \det \phi \det \psi$ without going to a specific basis. I get to,
$$\det (\phi \circ \psi) = \dfrac{\omega\big(\phi(\psi(e_1)), \dots, \phi(\psi(e_n))\big)}{\omega\left(e_1, \dots, e_n \right)}$$
and have no idea how to proceed. If doing so is possible, any hints on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried writing $\det \phi$ and $\det \psi$ in the basis $\psi(e_i)$ and $e_i$?

Comment: The key is that the exterior power is functorial.

Comment: @ZackFox I just got it, thank you very much! However, I have one more question if you don't mind. This seems to assume that $\psi(e_i)$ is indeed a basis and thus $\psi$ is an automorphism. If that were not the case then by the multilinearity and antisymmetry of $\omega$ I can show that $\omega(\psi(e_1), \dots, \psi(e_n)) = 0$ and then automatically the RHS is 0. How would I show that the LHS is zero in this case?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I'm not really familiar with the terminology, could you elaborate?

Comment: I think I just got it. If $\psi$ is not an automorphism then $\psi(e_i)$ are linearly dependent which implies that their images under $\phi$ are linearly independent too, so $\omega(\phi(\psi(e_1)), \dots, \phi(\psi(e_n))) = 0$ for the same reason. Is that correct?

Comment: Beware that [in characteristic 2, antisymmetric does not imply alternating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432673). I think your definition should use *alternating* $\omega$'s.

Comment: @AnneBauval I edited the question. Thanks for your caveat. I remember hearing before that fields of characteristic 2 are weird haha

Comment: Yes if it's not a basis, the numerator is 0, so both sides of your determinant identity are just 0. Otherwise, multiply and divide by $\omega(\psi...)$, and you get the product of determinants (by well-definedness, the choice of basis used to evaluate doesn't matter).

Comment: Thanks to everyone who commented, I just figured the answer out. Should the question then be closed? I'm not sure how to do that (or if I can do that).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Alternating multilinear maps factor through the exterior powers of $V$ by definition of exterior power; this naturally becomes a question about the exterior algebra. Transferring this problem to the exterior algebra a proving it there is not hard at all; is this something you'd be interested in?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff I am very interested in learning about exterior and Clifford algebras, that is in fact why I started learning multilinear algebra, so I would highly appreciate that, though my background in multilinear algebra isn't really very strong, I just recently learned what a multilinear map was. I know that's outside the scope of my original question, but I would also appreciate any sources you could point to for me to learn more about the subject. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Ext{{\textstyle\bigwedge}}
\newcommand\MVects[1]{\mathop{{\textstyle\bigwedge}^{\!#1}}}
\newcommand\K{\mathbb K}
\newcommand\form[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
$I will admit that I oversold myself a little. Determinants in the exterior algebra are easy, but actually linking this up with alternating multilinear functions does actually take some effort.

I will start by defining the exterior algebra, describing a little bit of its structure, and then showing the analogous result that you want in that context. Then I will show how this transfers to alternating multilinear maps. I should also note here that alternating tensors and the exterior algebra are not the same thing in nonzero characteristic; only when the characteristic is zero (like over $\mathbb R$) can these be made isomorphic.

A good reference for multilinear algebra, particularly involving the exterior algebra, is Werner Greub's *Multilinear Algebra*. However, I cannot promise that the way I do things below is the same way he does things.

#### The Exterior Algebra

The *exterior algebra* $\Ext V$ is the associative algebra generated by $V$ subject only to the relations $v\wedge v = 0$ for all $v \in V$, where it is traditional to write the algebra product as $\wedge$. Note that from this viewpoint $V \subseteq \Ext V$. Concretely, we construct $\Ext V$ by quotienting the tensor algebra by the ideal generated by $\{v\otimes v \;:\; v \in V\}$. What really matters, though, is its *universal property* which determines it uniquely up to isomorphism:

- Identify $V$ as a subset of $\Ext V$, and let $A$ be any associative algebra. Then every linear map $f : V \to A$ such that $f(v)^2 = 0$ extends uniquely to an algebra homomorphism $f' : \Ext V \to A$, i.e. $f'(v) = f(v)$ for all $v \in V$.

Of particular interest to us is the case $A = \Ext V$. If $f : V \to V$ is any linear map, then we can widen the codomain so that $f : V \to \Ext V$. Then the universal propery applies, and $f$ extends to a homomorphism $\Ext V \to \Ext V$; this is called the *outermorphism* of $f$, and we will use the same symbol $f$ to denote it.

We will also be interested in the *exterior powers* $\MVects kV$. These are analogous to tensor powers, but for alternating maps instead of just multilinear. They are also characterized by a universal propery:

- Let $W$ be another vector space. If $f : V^k \to W$ is an alternating multilinear map, then it extends uniquely to a *linear* map $f : \MVects kV \to W$ such that
  $$
    f(v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k) = f(v_1, v_2, \dotsc, v_k).
  $$
  Note that I've used the same symbol $f$ twice, though $f$ on the LHS and $f$ on the RHS are technically different objects.

As this notation suggests, we can identify $\MVects kV$ as a subspace of $\Ext V$, whereupon we find that $\Ext V$ is a *graded* algebra
$$
  \Ext V = \MVects0V\oplus\MVects1V\oplus\MVects2V\oplus\dotsb\oplus\MVects nV
$$
where we can identify $\MVects0V$ as the field of scalars and $\MVects1V = V$, and $n$ is the dimension of $V$.

Finally, the following lemma should be easy to establish:

- Let $v_1,\dotsc,v_k \in V$. Then $v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k = 0$ iff these vectors are linearly dependent.

#### Determinants

This is everything we need. By the previous lemma, $\MVects nV$ is a one dimensional space. Also by this lemma, the outermorphism of any $f : V \to V$ preserves grade. Thus there is a *unique* scalar $\det f$ such that for every $I \in \MVects nV$
$$
  f(I) = (\det f)I.
$$
In this way, we have *defined* the determinant $\det f$.

Now let $g : V \to V$ be any other linear function. No more need be said:
$$
  \det(f\circ g)I = (f\circ g)(I) = f(g(I)) = (\det f)g(I) = (\det f)(\det g)I.
$$

#### Alternating Multilinear Maps

Let $\K$ be our field of scalars. By the universal property of the exterior powers, any alternating multilinear $\phi : V^k \to \K$ can be considered as a map linear $\MVects kV \to \K$; in other words, it is an element of the dual space $\phi \in (\MVects kV)^*$. There is a *natural* bilinear pairing $\MVects kV^*\times\MVects kV \to \K$ given by
$$
  \form{\alpha_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge\alpha_k,\; v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_k}
= \det\Bigl(\alpha_i(v_j)\Bigr)_{i,j=1}^k.
$$
On the RHS we are taking the determinant of the matrix with entries $\alpha_i(v_j)$. Showing this is *natural* would take us too far astray, so I will simply use this as a definition. This pairing establishes linear isomorphisms $(\MVects kV)^* \cong \MVects kV^*$, in particular when $k = n$. To be concrete $\phi \in (\MVects kV)^*$ corresponds to a unique $\phi' \in \MVects kV^*$ such that
$$
  \phi(X) = \form{\phi', X}.
$$

We can also put all of these bilinear forms together into a form $\Ext V^*\times\Ext V \to \K$ by linearity and by declaring that $\form{X, Y} = 0$ when $X, Y$ have different grades. This establishes that there is a linear isomorphism $\psi : (\Ext V)^* \cong \Ext V^*$.

Now if $f : V \to V$ is linear, it has a dual $f^* : V^* \to V^*$. The above should make it straighforward to establish that the dual outermorphism $(\Ext V)^* \to (\Ext V)^*$ is exactly the dual of the outermorphism of $f^*$. Using e.g. $f_\wedge$ to denote outermorphisms for the moment, what I mean precisely is
$$
  \psi\circ(f_\wedge)^*\circ\psi^{-1} = (f^*)_\wedge.
$$
Thus, we will write
$$
  \form{X, f(Y)} = \form{f^*(X), Y}
$$
for any $X \in \Ext V^*$ and $Y \in \Ext V$.

It is well known that $\det f^* = \det f$ (this is the fact that the determinant of the transpose of a matrix is the determinant of the original matrix). Let $\phi \in (\MVects nV)^*$ and $\phi' = \psi(\phi) \in \MVects nV^*$, and let $X = v_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge v_n$ for $v_1,\dotsc,v_n \in V$. Then
$$
  \frac{\phi(f(v_1),\dotsc,f(v_n))}{\phi(v_1,\dotsc,v_n)}
= \frac{\form{\phi', f(X)}}{\form{\phi', X}}
= \frac{\form{f^*(\phi'), X}}{\form{\phi', X}}
= (\det f)\frac{\form{\phi', X}}{\form{\phi', X}}
= \det f.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it. I am currently reading through it. I'm struggling a bit because admittedly, I have not formally studied ring theory at any formal level of detail, so I'm not clear on some details, and I have also not covered the universal property in multilinear algebra yet. A little more context: I'm a first-year math major, I self-studied basic group theory from Artin and Linear algebra from Sheldon. Would you recommend that I proceed learning multilinear algebra and maybe pick up more ring theory along the way, or should I focus on ring theory first?

Comment: Also: would you recommend that I learn ring theory from Atiyah's introduction to commutative algebra? The preface says that the book is for students who have had a course in general algebra, but it starts by defining rings and ideals and so far I think I can follow the first two pages or so. I'm not sure if it's just because the book starts really easy (like most books do), and if my not having prior exposure to ring theory/field theory will come to bite me once I'm through with the first 10-20 pages.

Comment: @weirdmath I've not read Atiyah, nor really studied ring theory for that matter. I'm not sure what you are identifying as ring theory here; if you can specify what notions/arguments in my answer are difficult, then I can try to help. I don't see any reason you can't proceed with multilinear algebra. Though, I don't think you should worry too much about progressing "linearly" through any subject; study what you are interested in and where your curiosity/confusion leads you (though of course taking a class is a different matter).

Comment: The "universal properties" are most properly notions from category theory, but I wouldn't bother with that; it is good enough to understand them individually. A good exercise would be to prove that these universal properties define the exterior algebra and the exterior powers up to isomorphism. For the exterior algebra this would be an algebra isomorphism, and for the exterior powers this would be a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: I saw certain terms which I think are typically used in ring theory which I wasn't clear on (I did a bit of googling, I partially understand some now, but wouldn't say I'm really confident in any). Those include: 
the quotient of an algebra, the tensor algebra (in particular, what the direct summation is doing there, I don't think it's the same direct summation we use for subspaces of a vector space), ideals, grades (from what I understand, they have to do with the direct summation too).

Comment: I don't want to bother you with explaining all of that, it's really nice of you to write that long answer to begin with. I would just appreciate you pointing me to any pdf/chapter of a book that summarizes some of these notions so that I can hopefully comprehend your answer better. Wikipedia doesn't really cut it that much...

Comment: @weirdmath Ah, ok. You are right that quotient-by-an-ideal and gradation are ring theoretic. I would call the tensor algebra part of linear algebra. The direct sum $\oplus$ with the exterior powers is indeed a vector space direct sum; in this case, the exterior powers are vector subspaces of the exterior algebra. If you meant the $v\otimes v$, this is the traditional symbol for the algebra product of the tensor algebra.

Comment: For some basic group/right/field theory and a bit of linear algebra, I used Michael Artin's "Algebra" in undergrad; this book is perfectly fine. It will **not** cover gradation or the tensor algebra. Greub covers the tensor algebra starting in the first chapter. You should probably read about dual vector spaces: Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* is very popular and certainly covers this; Sergei Treil's [*Linear Algebra Done Wrong*](https://www.math.brown.edu/streil/papers/LADW/LADW.html) will also cover this, is what I used in undergrad, and is free.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt at a self-answer (guided by the hint given by @Zack Fox). I had to do it by cases and would appreciate a constructively-valid proof if somebody can provide one.

Case 1: If $\psi$ is an automorphism, then $\{\psi(e_i)\}$ is a basis of V, and since $\det \phi$ is independent of our choice of basis, we have,
$$ \det \phi = \dfrac{\omega \bigg(\phi \big(\psi(e_1) \big), \dots, \phi \big(\psi(e_n) \big) \bigg)}{\omega \big(\psi(e_1), \dots, \psi(e_n) \big)} .$$

Thus,
\begin{align}
\det \phi \det \psi &= \dfrac{\omega \bigg(\phi \big(\psi(e_1) \big), \dots, \phi \big(\psi(e_n) \big) \bigg)}{\omega \big(\psi(e_1), \dots, \psi(e_n) \big)} \cdot \dfrac{\omega \big(\psi(e_1), \dots, \psi(e_n) \big)}{\omega(e_1, \dots, e_n)} \\ 
&= \dfrac{\omega \bigg(\phi \big(\psi(e_1) \big), \dots, \phi \big(\psi(e_n) \big) \bigg)}{\omega(e_1, \dots, e_n)} \equiv \det (\phi \circ \psi).
\end{align}

Case 2: If $\psi$ is not an automorphism, then $\{\psi(e_i)\}$ is linearly dependent and so is $\phi \big( \{\psi(e_i)\} \big)$. Thus, $$ \omega \big(\psi(e_1), \dots, \psi(e_n) \big) = \omega \bigg(\phi \big(\psi(e_1) \big), \dots, \phi \big(\psi(e_n) \big) \bigg) = 0.$$

Putting all of that together,
$$\det (\phi \circ \psi) \equiv \dfrac{\omega \bigg(\phi \big(\psi(e_1) \big), \dots, \phi \big(\psi(e_n) \big) \bigg)}{\omega(e_1, \dots, e_n)} = 0 \\ = \det \phi \cdot \dfrac{\omega \big(\psi(e_1), \dots, \psi(e_n) \big)}{\omega(e_1, \dots, e_n)} = \det \phi \det \psi. $$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to see it using old-fashioned matrices. It's essentially as the other proofs given here.

What you've written is the fact that if $C_1, \dots, C_n$ are the columms of a matrix $A$, then if $d(C_1, \dots, C_n)$ is an alternating multilinear function such that $d(e_1, \dots, e_n) = 1$, then $d(C_1, \dots, C_n) = \det A$.

This implies that if $f(C_1, \dots, C_n)$ is an alternating multilinear function, then
$$
f(C_1, \dots, C_n) = f(e_1, \dots, e_n)d(C_1, \dots, C_n).
$$

Now, given a matrix $B$, the function
$$
f(C_1, \dots, C_n) = d(BC_1, \dots, BC_n).
$$
is alternating multilinear. Since $BC_1, \dots, BC_n$ are the columns of $BA$, it follows that \begin{align*}
\det(BA) &= d(BC_1, \dots, BC_n)\\
&=f(C_1, \dots, C_n)\\
&= f(e_1, \dots, e_n)d(C_1, \dots, C_n)\\
&= d(Be_1, \dots, Be_n)\det A\\
&= (\det B)(\det A).
\end{align*}